# Set input to a controller input using button onclick method in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I find myself struggling to change the form input value from the button onClick handler. My problem is escalated by the  fact that I have the line items on a form and things become even more complex that way. I tried to bring in a ref to set value,,, the value is displayed but at the form state after submission it remains empty which means the value is not being set. Below are all my code files. May someone kindly help me on where I may be missing the point.

```
class VehicleTemplate extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8000/ws/weightData/');
    this.socketRef = null;
    this.state = {
        data: 0,
        name: '',
        model: '',
        plate_number: '',
        type: 'truck',
        wagons: [{ index: uuid(), label: '', type: 'once', weight: '' }],
        total: 0,
      };
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleChange= this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleChangeTable = this.handleChangeTable.bind(this);
    this.addNewRow = this.addNewRow.bind(this);
    this.deleteRow = this.deleteRow.bind(this);
    this.handleLineItemChange = this.handleLineItemChange.bind(this);
  }


  componentDidMount() {
    this.ws.onopen = () => {
        // on connecting, do nothing but log it to the console
        console.log('connected')
    }

    this.ws.onmessage = evt => {
        // listen to data sent from the websocket server
        // const message = JSON.parse(evt.data)
        const {data} = this.state;
        this.setState({data: evt.data})
        // this.setState({this.state.lines.weight: data})
    }

    this.ws.onclose = () => {
        console.log('disconnected')
        // automatically try to reconnect on connection loss
    }

  };



  onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const {
      name,
      model,
      plate_number,
      type,
      wagons,

    } = this.state;

    const vehicle = {
      name,
      model,
      plate_number,
      type,
      wagons,
    };

    this.props.addVehicle(vehicle, this.props.token);
    console.log(vehicle);
    this.setState({
      name: '',
      model: '',
      plate_number: '',
      wagons: [],
    });

  };



  handleLineItemChange = (elementIndex) => (event) => {
    let wagons = this.state.wagons.map((item, i) => {
      if (elementIndex !== i) return item
      return {...item, [event.target.name]: event.target.value}
    })
    this.setState({wagons})
  }



  handleChange = name => event => {
    this.setState({
      [name]: event.target.value,
    });
  };





  handleChangeTable = (name, id) => event => {
    this.updateItem(id, { [name]: event.target.value });
  };



  addNewRow = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      wagons: this.state.wagons.concat(
        [{index: uuid(), label: '', type: 'once', weight: ''  }]
      )
    })
  }

  deleteRow = (index) => (event) => {
    this.setState({
      wagons: this.state.wagons.filter((item, i) => {
        return index !== i
      })
    })
  }



  handleReorderLineItems = (newLineItems) => {
    this.setState({
      wagons: newLineItems,
    })
  }

  clickOnDelete(record) {
      this.setState({
          wagons: this.state.lines.filter(r => r !== record)
      });
  }

 

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    const {
      data,
      name,
      model,
      plate_number,
      wagons,

    } = this.state;

    return (
      <InformationTechnologyLayout>
        <PapperBlock title="ADD VEHICLE" icon="ios-document-outline" desc="VEHICLE">
          <Form>
              <div style={{ clear: 'both' }} />
              <h1>WEIGHT: {data}KG</h1>
              <Grid container>
                <Grid item xs={6}>
                  <Controls.Input
                      name="name"
                      label="Name"
                      value={name}
                      onChange={this.handleChange('name')}
                  />
                  <Controls.Input
                      name="model"
                      label="MODEL"
                      value={model}
                      onChange={this.handleChange('model')}
                  />
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={6}>
                  <Controls.Input
                      name="plate_number"
                      label="PLATE NUMBER"
                      value={plate_number}
                      onChange={this.handleChange('plate_number')}
                  />
                </Grid>
              </Grid>
              <Extensions
                items={wagons}
                addHandler={this.addNewRow}
                changeHandler={this.handleLineItemChange}
                focusHandler={this.handleFocusSelect}
                deleteHandler={this.deleteRow}
                reorderHandler={this.handleReorderLineItems}
                data ={data}
              />
              <div className='valueTable'>
                <div className='row'>
                  <div className='label'>Subtotal</div>
                  <div className='value'>{this.calcLineItemsTotal()}KG</div>
                </div>
                <div className='row'>
                  <div className='label'>Total Due</div>
                  <div className='value'>{this.calcGrandTotal()}KG</div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <Button variant="contained" onClick={this.onSubmit}>SUBMIT</Button>


          </Form>
        </PapperBlock>
      </InformationTechnologyLayout>
    );
  }
}
```

On top is the main form component which has got Vehicle exetnsions and I am getting my weight from a websocket connection streaming scale outputs.

```
class Extensions extends Component {

  handleDragEnd = (result) => {
    if (!result.destination) return

    // helper function to reorder result (src: react-beautiful-dnd docs)
    const reorder = (list, startIndex, endIndex) => {
      const result = Array.from(list)
      const [removed] = result.splice(startIndex, 1)
      result.splice(endIndex, 0, removed)
      return result
    }

    // perform reorder
    const lineItems = reorder(
      this.props.items,
      result.source.index,
      result.destination.index
    )

    // call parent handler with new state representation
    this.props.reorderHandler(lineItems)

  }

  render = () => {

    const {
        items,
        addHandler,
        changeHandler,
        focusHandler,
        deleteHandler,
        reorderHandler,
        products,
        data,
        readOnly,
        } = this.props

    return (
      <form>

        <div className='lineItems'>
          <div className='gridTable'>



            <DragDropContext onDragEnd={this.handleDragEnd}>
              <Droppable droppableId="droppable">
                {(provided, snapshot) => (
                  <div
                    ref={provided.innerRef}
                    className= 'listDraggingOver'
                  >
                    {this.props.items.map((item, i) => (
                      <Draggable key={item.index} draggableId={item.index} index={i}>
                        {(provided, snapshot) => (
                          <div
                            ref={provided.innerRef}
                            {...provided.draggableProps}
                            {...provided.dragHandleProps}
                            style={provided.draggableProps.style}
                            className='listItemDragging'
                          >
                            <Extension
                              addHandler={addHandler}
                              changeHandler={changeHandler}
                              focusHandler={focusHandler}
                              deleteHandler={deleteHandler}
                              reorderHandler={reorderHandler}
                              data={data}
                              style={{color: 'red'}}
                              key={i + item.index}
                              index={i}
                              name={item.index}
                              label={item.label}
                              weight={item.weight}
                            />
                          </div>
                        )}
                      </Draggable>
                    ))}
                    {provided.placeholder}
                  </div>
                )}
            </Droppable>
          </DragDropContext>

          </div>

          <div className='addItem'>
            <button type="button" onClick={addHandler}><AddIcon size="1.25em" className='addIcon' /> Add Item</button>
          </div>

        </div>
      </form>

    )
  }
}
```

This are the extensions and the last file is where I would like to capture weight from

```
class LineItem extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.ref = React.createRef();
    this.state = {
      buttonState: false,
    };

  }

  requestWeight = () => {
    const { weight } = this.props;
    const {buttonState} =this.state;
    this.ref.current.value = this.props.data;
    this.setState({
      buttonState: true
    })
  };


  render = () => {

    const { index, label, weight } = this.props;
    const {buttonState} = this.state;

    return (
      <div className='lineItem'>
            <div>{index + 1}</div>
            <Controls.Input
                  name="label"
                  label="LABEL"
                  value={label}
                  onChange={this.props.changeHandler(index)}
            />

            <input
                className='currency'
                type='number'
                readOnly={true}
                ref={this.ref}
                name='weight'
                onChange={this.props.changeHandler(index)}
              />
            <div>
              <button type="button"
                className='requestItems'
                onClick={this.requestWeight}
                disabled={buttonState}

              >REQUEST WEIGHT</button>
            </div>
            <div>
              <button type="button"
                className='deleteItem'
                onClick={this.props.deleteHandler(index)}
              ><DeleteIcon size="1.25em" /></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
  }
}

export default LineItem
```

If I add the value and put weight on the input then the ref stops working. I assume I might be missing something between my handleChange function and the requestWeight function but I really dont know what exaclty

Comment: Please supply only the code that is necessary to help you.

Comment: @hellogoodnight I appreciate but the thing is with just few lines I had thought one would find it difficult to see where my problem emanates from. As explained in my description. There seem to be a problem in the hadleLineItemChange and requestWeight function and the input field in weight field in the last file